# How to create a new table, based on existing table with dynamic content, but keeping the history in the new table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

i have a table (OriginalTable) with ~350 records that have uniqueID and the records decrees/increase/update over time.

I want to create a new table (NewTable) based on these records, but keep all records in NewTable even if they drop out of the OriginalTable. This raises some question:

1. How do i keep all records in NewTable when copying from OriginalTable ?
2. What is best-practice for activating a daily procedure to copy content from OriginalTable to NewTable?
   *- create a job with the SQL Server Agent?*
3. I cant see the SQL Server Agent in MS management studio, does that mean i dont have the neccessary priviliges? (It's an elastic-pool db - Azure)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you simply want something like this?

```
insert into newtable ( . . . )
    select . . .
    from oldtables o
    where not exists (select 1 from newtable n where n.uniquekey = o.uniquekey);
```

Such a query can be scheduled to run periodically using a job in SQL Server Agent.

Comment: I guess so, but need to understand whats going on. What does the 'o'o behind oldtables represent? And why "Select 1...." ?

Comment: @otk . . . `o` is a *table alias*, a basic part of SQL syntax.  The `select 1` is because `exists` checks whether or not any *rows* are returned; the column values don't matter.  `1` is easy to type.

Comment: When using an alias, do you not have to use the keyword AS?: from oldtables  AS o
And do '1' mean 'Column 1' ?

Comment: @otk . . . No.  I always use `as` for column aliases and never for table aliases.